# Async Validator Throw Expected validator to return Promise or Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have tried to confirm the password with password value. I have done as per Async validator standard. But I am wondering it's not working and throw me the following error. Please tell anyone how to solve this error.

> Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.

Here is my code.

Call Validators:

```
cPass: ['', Validators.compose([
  Validators.required, 
  Validators.maxLength(32),
  Validators.minLength(10)
]),
  this.validPassword.bind(this)
]
```

Custom Validation funciton:

```
validPassword(control: AbstractControl) {            
  const isEqual = Observable.of(this.password == control.value);
  return isEqual ? { valid : true } : null;         
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error speaks for itself:

> Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.

You're returning `object|null` in your `function`.

Just change it to:

```
validPassword(control: AbstractControl) {
  return observableOf('12345678910' === control.value).pipe(
    map(result => result ? { invalid: true } : null)
  );
}
```

<kbd>[**STABKBLITZ DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-ezdaep)</kbd>